# How to validate and read claims from Azure AD B2C token in ASP.NET MVC Web API

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have an existing Asp.net MVC Web API Project and my Startup(OwinStartUp) file code has

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
     WebApiConfig.Configure(app);
}
```

I have to build a new API which has to Authenticate Azure AD B2C token and read the claims for further processing.

How to can I achieve this using middleware? I am not able to succeed using UseJwtBearerAuthentication

Answer (score 0):

See [this sample app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi) that uses OWIN w/ B2C.

More specifically [this code](http://%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20void%20ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder%20app)):

```cs
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    TokenValidationParameters tvps = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        // Accept only those tokens where the audience of the token is equal to the client ID of this app
        ValidAudience = ClientId,
        AuthenticationType = Startup.DefaultPolicy
    };

    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        // This SecurityTokenProvider fetches the Azure AD B2C metadata & signing keys from the OpenIDConnect metadata endpoint
        AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(tvps, new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider(String.Format(AadInstance, Tenant, DefaultPolicy)))
    });
}
```